# show all entries based on author of current entry

Tags: members, author

I have a simple blog displaying a single entry using segment _2 as the url title.

I want to display a list on this same page that displays links to read other entries by the same author.

The only way I have been able to do ti so far is by adding the author_id to segment 3 but that is not acceptable to the client.

Is there an embed method or something else where I can display the other entries from the same author without using a segment to get the author id?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" entry_url="{segment_2}" limit="1" dynamic="yes"}
{title}
{content}

Other Entries by {author}
 {/exp:channel:entries}

<ul>
 {exp:channel:entries channel="blog"  limit="12" dynamic="no" author_id="???"}
<li><a href="{title_permalink=blog}">{title}</a></li>
</ul>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

using an embed here is the embed:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="commentary" limit="12" dynamic="no" author_id="{embed:author_id}"}
<li><a href="{title_permalink=commentary-test}/">{title}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Parent page:

```
{embed="commentary-test/author" author_id="{author_id}"}
```